# Hbase Regions for a table served from same region server

Tags: hbase

I have a hbase table which has got 10 regions and all regions are served by the same Region Server.

There are 3 Datanodes in my cluster and the replication factor 3. I can see there are 10 hdfs blcok size inside hdfs and each block is 128 MB and replicated properly across all the data nodes.

There are more tables which are facing the same issues. Though the regions served by each Region Server is balanced, the regions for most of the tables are are not distributed.

This has something to do with any configuration issues?

I am using Clouder Distribution - 5.3.0 which uses hbase 0.98.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hbase balancer makes every region server has similar amount of region responsibility, but it does not consider load on tables or size of tables. You can assign regions to another server in shell if you want but it is not easy for many regions. I also suggest reading this hbase task https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3373